# Node.js SerialPort Loop Ports Check Available port execute AT Commands

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I have 8 port SMS modem I want to check available ports then execute commands if the port was in used it will check available ports
here is the code

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var serialPort = SerialPort.serialPort;

SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    if(port.manufacturer == 'FTDI'){
      //console.log(port.comName, port.pnpId, port.manufacturer);
      var port = new SerialPort(port.comName , {
        baudRate: 115200,  dataBits: 8,  parity: 'none',  stopBits: 1, flowControl: false, xon : false, rtscts:false, xoff:false, xany:false, buffersize:0
      });

      port.on("open", onOpen);
      port.on('error', onError); 
      port.on('data', onDataReceived);

      async function onOpen(error) {
        if(!error){
            console.log('Port open sucessfully');
            console.log(port.comName)
            if(port.isOpen == true){
                await send(port, "0XXXXXXXXXX", "Hi Test");
                await read(port);
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the issue you need help with?

Comment: I can't break the loop once the sms was sent and also if there is a used port its not continuing to loop